# Ruby's range step method causes very slow execution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, date-range

I've got this block of code:

```
date_counter = Time.mktime(2011,01,01,00,00,00,"+05:00")
@weeks = Array.new
(date_counter..Time.now).step(1.week) do |week|
   logger.debug "WEEK: " + week.inspect
   @weeks << week
end
```

Technically, the code works, outputting:

```
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 -0500 2011
Sat Jan 08 00:00:00 -0500 2011
Sat Jan 15 00:00:00 -0500 2011
etc.
```

But the execution time is complete rubbish! It takes approximately four seconds to compute each week.

Is there some grotesque inefficiency that I'm missing in this code? It seems straight-forward enough.

I'm running Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming MRI and Rubinius use similar methods to generate the range the basic algorithm used with all the extraneous checks and a few Fixnum optimisations etc. removed is:

```
class Range
  def each(&block)
    current = @first
    while current < @last
      yield current
      current = current.succ
    end
  end

  def step(step_size, &block)
    counter = 0
    each do |o|
      yield o if counter % step_size = 0
      counter += 1
    end
  end
end
```

(See [the Rubinius source code](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/3d1c9220b83bb610fdf1b19f4d6a0a7c5c7a8600/kernel/common/range.rb#L250-282))

For a `Time` object `#succ` returns the time one second later.  So even though you are asking it for just each week it has to step through every second between the two times anyway.

#### Edit: Solution

Build a range of Fixnum's since they have an optimised `Range#step` implementation.
Something like:

```
date_counter = Time.mktime(2011,01,01,00,00,00,"+05:00")
@weeks = Array.new

(date_counter.to_i..Time.now.to_i).step(1.week).map do |time|
  Time.at(time)
end.each do |week|
  logger.debug "WEEK: " + week.inspect
  @weeks << week
end
```

Comment: So it does, essentially, have to generate the entire six million entry array if you're not using Fixnums. And even worse, it has to do so using six million calls to `.succ`.

Comment: There is a big difference between simply iterating over all the values and actually generating the array: `time ruby -e "(0..6e6).each { |i| p i }" >/dev/null` => 10 secs, `time ruby -e "(0..6e6).to_a.each { |i| p i }" >/dev/null` => 30 secs

Comment: My point is that it has to generate all the values individually as the Range has no way of chunking itself without doing it the hard way (unless it is a Range of Fixnum). So, it has to build the whole thing even if it isn't doing it with an intermediate Array.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for the "use Fixnum" solution.

Comment: Spectacular answer, thanks Nemo! I am in awe of your Ruby-fu.

Comment: A friendly warning for a potential bug using Nemo157's code:
Weeks where daylight saving time ends are 1 hour longer than a normal week. Converting time to integers and iterating using 1.week may result in going from monday at 0:00 (with DST) to sunday at 23:00 (without DST) the same week and one's iteration would be faulty.

Comment: I had the same problem with something like `(1594609200 .. 1594688400).step(1.hour).each{|x| puts x}`, where the step was not a Fixnum, I solved it by using `1.hour.to_i` (also, this popped up when upgrading from ruby 2.4.0 to 2.6.x, it seemd to run okay before)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are missing a gross inefficiency. Try this in irb to see what you're doing:

```
(Time.mktime(2011,01,01,00,00,00,"+05:00") .. Time.now).each { |x| puts x }
```

The range operator is going from January 1 to now in increments of **one second** and that's a huge list. Unfortunately, Ruby isn't clever enough to combine the range generation and the one-week chunking into a single operation so it has to build the entire ~6million entry list.

BTW, "straight forward" and "gross inefficiency" are not mutually exclusive, in fact they're often concurrent conditions.

**UPDATE**: If you do this:

```
(0 .. 6000000).step(7*24*3600) { |x| puts x }
```

Then the output is produced almost instantaneously. So, it appears that the problem is that Range doesn't know how to optimize the chunking when faced with a range of Time objects but it can figure things out quite nicely with Fixnum ranges.

Comment: I haven't looked at the MRI source, but I'm almost completely certain that `Range#each` and `Range#step` don't actually build the array.

Comment: @Nemo157: The execution time says otherwise. You can watch `(Time.mktime(2011,01,01,00,00,00,"+05:00") .. Time.now).step(7*24*3600) { |x| puts x }` working in 1.8.7 but it should be nearly instantaneous if it was combining the generation and chunking. OTOH, it is very fast with Fixnum instead of Time.

Comment: Yes the execution is slow, but it still isn't building the array.    The slowness comes from the Range not knowing how to increment anything other than a Fixnum by anything other than a single step.  It has to step through every value with `#succ` but it doesn't actually build any array during that.

Comment: Something else that might be contributing to the range's drag is Time#usec. Not only is Time handling seconds, but microseconds. It might not display them, but it keeps track of them in its computations. Converting to Fixnum chops that precision off entirely.

Comment: @the Tin Man: The time object maybe know about µs but I don't think it applies: (a) calling `t.succ` where `t` is a `Time` just increments by 1s, (b) `Range` has specific `Fixnum` optimizations as Nemo157 notes, and (c) `Range` falls back to calling `.succ` when it doesn't know what else to do (thanks to Nemo157 again). I think the `Fixnum` optimization is the real issue here.